# Translation of smooth curves

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry

Let $\Gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ be a smooth rectifiable closed curve that doesnt self intersect. Is it possible to find $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ intersecion $\Gamma\cap(\Gamma+\epsilon)$ is finite?(where $\Gamma+\epsilon=\{z+\epsilon|\:z\in\Gamma\}$) If not what class of curves satisfies this property?

Comment: The trace of the curve must not contain any horizontal segment. I don't think that will be sufficient, however.

Comment: The curve $\{t+\mathrm{i}\sin(t)\mid t \in \mathbb{R}$ always has an infinite number of intersections, as do lines of constant imaginary part.  Clearly, if $\Gamma$ satisfies the "horizontal line test", it will have an empty real (nonzero) translated intersection.  Spirals asymptotically approaching zero have an infinite number of self intersections under small real translation, so boundedness won't cut it...

Comment: $t \mapsto t+it^2$ will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you require the curve to be closed, the answer is simple: there are no such curves $\Gamma$. Indeed, by the Jordan curve theorem $\Gamma$ divides $\mathbb C$ in two components. Let $D $ be the bounded component.

The curve   $\Gamma+\epsilon$ is not be contained in $D$, and does not meet $\Gamma$: thus, it lies in the exterior of $\Gamma$.  Therefore, the region it bounds, namely $D+\epsilon$, is disjoint from $D$. But this is impossible: since $D$ is open, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the sets $D$ and $D+\epsilon$ have a common point.

---

If $\Gamma$ is **not** assumed to be closed, the comments apply: if $\Gamma$ satisfies the "horizontal line test", any $\epsilon$ works; otherwise expect intersections.